# How can I put every list of lists in a csv column in python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm developing a script in python that gets data from a log file and I need to save every type of data into a respective column. I'm using regex to obtain the data.

This is a part of my code where I get this result:

[image: Click to view the image]

```
#Getting data from log as list using regex
fecha = re.findall('\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}', str(listaValores))
hora = re.findall('\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}', str(listaValores))

#List of lists about data obtained
valoresFinales = [fecha, hora]

#Putting into .csv
with open("resultado.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    wr.writerows(valoresFinales)
```

**What I want**

[image: Click to view the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give the `writerows` function a list of two elements, so you get two rows of data in the end.

Instead you want to give it something like [`zip(fecha, hora)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open("resultado.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    wr.writerows(zip(*valoresFinales))
```